# st_instersect fails with two sf files

Tags: r, r-sf

I got two RDS spatial files and I need to crop one with the other but I am getting an error message. The files are not very large and are located here: https://login.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6c6987615e75b19fa8 . Could someone let me know what am I doing wrong? Code is below:

```
library(sf)
mesoam <- readRDS("mesoam.rds")
 primate_polys <- readRDS("primate_polys.rds")  
primates_meso2 <- st_instersection(primate_polys, mesoam)

Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  : 
  Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 2778 crosses edge 2780
```

Comment: one of your polygons has self-intersections. you can try using `sf::st_make_valid()` on them before doing the intersection

Comment: I read about it but couldn't use it on my example. is it `st_make_valid` used on both shapefiles at the same time or separately?

Comment: I did `st_make_valid(mesoam)` and `st_make_valid(primate_polys)` and ran without errors but when I perform  `st_intersection(primate_polys, mesoam)` I get the same error message again.

Comment: did you re-assign the objects: `mesoam <- st_make_valid(mesoam)` and `primate_polys <- st_make_valid(primate_polys)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` and that takes care of the problem.